# what is the simplest way to send and receive a basic soap message from C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap

I know the information needed for this question is readily available, but it seems like there are several options and I just need to send a very simple message. I was planning on just building a string containing the entire SOAP message and sending that. But every example I come across seems like they are doing quite a bit more. I don't need to set up a service, I just need to communicate with one. I will only need to retrieve one element from the returned message.

Do I need to create a `.amx` file? Do I need to do any of the other visual studio specific things or can I just include some library and send my message?

Comment: You don't need to use a library, or to construct SOAP messages in XML. Just use "Add Service Reference" and point it to your WSDL. Visual Studio will create all the code you need to call the service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using WCF since it does everything for you.
In Visual Studio, add a Service Reference to the project, it'll generate a client proxy for you.

Outside Visual Studio, you can use `svcutil.exe` to achieve the same thing.